# Matlab rgb2hsv() to give uint8s?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, rgb, hsv

I'm new at working with Matlab and I am trying to get the HSV values of an image, but I need the result to be an uint8.  Currently, when I read in an image, I received the following matrix:

```
whos im
Name        Size               Bytes  Class    Attributes

im        120x100x3            36000  uint8
```

When I use the function rgb2hsv() i get:

```
hsv = rgb2hsv(im);
whos hsv
Name        Size                Bytes  Class     Attributes

hsv       120x100x3            288000  double
```

Is there any way to either convert this to a matrix of uint8s instead of doubles?

Comment: Converting to `uint8` will have unintended side effects.  You will **lose precision** if you convert to `uint8`.  Usually, the hue is represented as an angular measure between 0 and 360 while the saturation and value are represented as floating point values from 0 to 100 or from 0 to 1.  The transformation is **supposed** to give you floating point values.  Let me ask you a question instead: **Why** do you want to convert the result to `uint8`?

Comment: I need to use the values as indexes for a separate matrix.  It's okay if I lose a bit of precision.

Comment: Would you mind explaining what your ultimate application of using the HSV transformation as indices are?  It may provide some further insight and I could comment on another method if applicable.

Comment: I'm working on a project for my computer vision class.  We need to detect if a pixel is member of a person's face or not.  Our professor gave us some insight by saying we can use rgb values as well as hue and saturation to provide better accuracy for face detection.  I have a matrix which represents probability that based off a RGB and HS value a pixel is likely to be either a member of a face or not.  This is why I needed the the hue and saturation values to be uints.

Comment: Ok that makes more sense.  As such, the quantization of the HSV transformation seems plausible.  Thanks very much.  Good luck.

Comment: FYI, `hsv` is the name of a built-in colormap. You might not want to overwrite it if you're using that color scheme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert the result back to uint8, simply use `hsv = im2uint8(rgb2hsv(im))`. It not only does the data type conversion, but also scales your image to the 0...255 range of an uint8.

When storing an image in double format, only the range 0...1 is used, while storing an image in any integer (or fixed point) format the full range between `intmin` and `intmax` is used. To convert the image back to the original range you have to use `im2uint8` or do it manually, first multiplying by 255 and then converting the data type. I prefer `im2uint8` because it is more robust, e.g. `im2uint8(im2uint8(I))` returns a valid image. The previous is true for all colour spaces I know except HDR images.

I know that the documentation says it's for grey scale and rgb images only, but it's basically a data type conversion with automatic rescaling.

Comment: is it safe to scale `hsv` values? Do they "behave" like RGB values?

Comment: @Shai: Yes it is, added some explanations. You obviously get some quantisation errors, but nothing different than RGB.